# Get rid of TouchWiz

Tags: samsung-touchwiz

I recently bought Samsung XCover 3 and I like HW part of the phone, but TouchWiz is hell. Is there any way I can get rid of it completely?

I installed different launcher, which helped a lot, but many features works differently from clean Android - settings, many annoying pop-ups, speed issues ...

Comment: No better options? Can I just uninstall it somehow? Can I found somewhere completely clean Android?

Comment: No, you can't uninstall it – it's too deeply integrated with the system. Only options are alternative launchers, or alternative ROMs.